# EventTrigger и анимация

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Никак не могу разобраться с анимацией. Я пытаюсь сделать что то эдакое:

```
<Button Content="x" Width="25" Height="25">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Name="x0"/>
                <Label Name="x1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>            
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="x0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" To="Red"/>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="x1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" To="White"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Но так вообще выдает ошибку компиляции: свойство TargetName не может быть задано для типа Style Setter. В общем то если конкретно это должна быть кнопка для закрытия вкладки в TabControl, что то по типу того как в хроме сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается вот как.

Во-первых, стиль не видит имена, определённые в темплейте, поэтому триггеры я перенёс в темплейт.

Во-вторых, чтение происходит сверху вниз, поэтому я добавил триггеры после контента, чтобы имена были видимы.

В-третьих, вы не можете анимировать `Brush`, анимировать можно лишь цвет. Но чтобы добраться до цвета, нужно установить его вручную, чтобы быть уверенным в том, что наш `Brush` есть `SolidColorBrush`, а не что-то непонятное.

В-четвёртых, чтобы доступиться до цвета, нужно использовать странную. конструкцию вида `Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)` (означает: возьми свойство `Fill`, найди в этом объекте свойство `Color` (или dependency property, или attached property), определённое в типе `SolidColorBrush`.

Результат:

```
<Button Content="x" Width="25" Height="25">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Name="x0">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <Label Name="x1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Label.Foreground>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="x0"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="x1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

---

Если нужно мгновенное изменение, то достаточно триггеров с сеттарами.

```
<Button Content="x" Width="25" Height="25">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Name="x0"/>
                <Label Name="x1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="x0" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="x1" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: не совсем так... Во первых анимация слишком плавная. Мне фактически никакая анимация и не нужна. Мне нужно чтобы просто мгновенно кнопка стала красной. Во вторых надо чтобы когда убираешь мышку с кнопки все возвращалось обратно как было, а сейчас не возвращается.

Comment: @DarkByte: Анимацию я не трогал, она осталась как вы написали. Так что претензии тут не ко мне. А если нужно мгновенно — тогда да, лучше наверное триггеры. Ну и чтобы возвращалось, нужна обратная анимация, понятно. Или обратный триггер.

Comment: а как сделать мгновенно? В смысле триггеры? Какие триггеры? У меня что не триггер чтоли? А то что касается возврата, разве оно не должно автоматически возвращать??? Обычно так бывает с триггерами...

Comment: @DarkByte: Это с DataTrigger'ами. Сейчас перепишу.

Comment: как это с DataTrigger'ами??? Ведь мне нужно именно по срабатывания события! Это же EventTrigger, разве нет?

Comment: @DarkByte: Представьте себе :) Обновил ответ.

Comment: офигеть :D А если я хочу чтобы при нажатии цвет меняло? И соответственно при отпускании обратно вернуть.

Comment: и еще, не смотря на установленное центрирование текста он все таки как то смещается и например если установить размер кнопки не 25х25, а 15х15 крестика вообще не видно становится... Как исправить?

Comment: @DarkByte: Этот вопрос уже не относится к данной теме. С изменениями цветов всё в порядке?

Comment: @DarkByte: Для нажатия поставьте триггер на `IsPressed`.

Comment: да спасибо все работает!!!

Comment: хотя стоп, а все таки как быть со смещением текста? Это как раз относится к теме.

Comment: @DarkByte: Смещение текста не относится к анимации, вы ж спрашивали про неё?

Comment: блин, ну что сложно ответить? Про триггер на нажатие вы же ответили... Что мне теперь ради этого новую тему создавать?

Comment: И потом я спрашивал не только про анимацию, а про кнопку "как в хроме". А в хроме не смещается никуда этот крестик.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39118/discussion-between-dark-byte-and-vladd).