# TabItem с кнопкой для закрытия

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я хочу сделать TabItem для TabControl-а с кнопкой закрывающей его как в браузерах. Вот что я набросал:

```
<Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Name="BG"/>
                    <Path Name="PATH" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"
                      Data="M 0 0 M 0.3 0.3 L 0.7 0.7 M 0.3 0.7 L 0.7 0.3 M 1 1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BG" Property="Fill" Value="#DB4437"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PATH" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BG" Property="Fill" Value="#A8352A"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PATH" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ClosableTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Button Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Но когда я использую это то кнопку не видно вообще...

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test" Style="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemStyle}" Width="100"/>
</TabControl>
```

Зато если убрать Header то ее становится видно.

Обновил.

```
<Style x:Key="ClosableTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button Name="CLOSE"
                            Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" 
                            Width="15" 
                            Height="15" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" 
                            Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
                            Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="CLOSE" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ага, я нашёл в чём дело. Сейчас напишу :)

Comment: Такой вопрос, как ты привязываешь команду закрытия к создаваемой TabItem? Точнее говоря, как ты объявляешь команду CloseCommand, что объявлен в стиле (Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы устанавливаете `Header` один раз в стиле, а другой раз непосредственно, и это второе присвоение сильнее.

Вам нужно вместо этого установить `HeaderTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="ClosableTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" MinWidth="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test" Style="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemStyle}"/>
</TabControl>
```

Результат:

[image: тест]

---

Обновление: показывать/убирать кнопку в зависимости от состояния TabItem'а тоже просто. Надо привязаться к нужному свойству через конвертер:

```
<Style x:Key="ClosableTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" MinWidth="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Вот такой код

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test 1" Style="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemStyle}"/>
    <TabItem Header="Test 2" Style="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemStyle}"/>
</TabControl>
```

даёт теперь такую картинку:

[image: тест 2]

Comment: как понять запись Content="{Binding}"? К чему биндинг?

Comment: @DarkByte: К `DataContext`!

Comment: как может быть биндинг к DataContext? О_о Никогда такого не видел...

Comment: а вот я еще хотел триггер сделать к свойству IsSelected чтобы когда вкладка не активна - кнопка скрывалась и под текст было бы больше места (так например в яндекс-браузере сделано). Но че то у меня не видит имя кнопки.

Comment: @DarkByte: да запросто! :) Обновил ответ

Comment: это не встроенный конвертер? Зачем это надо? Не проще сделать триггером?

Comment: А да увидел. Встроенный это хорошо. Но проблема в том что также надо чтобы при наведении даже на не выбранный итем кнопка становилась видимой.

Comment: И еще хотелось бы подсказку с текстом Header-а при наведении. :) Я пытался, но че то не смог прибиндиться...

Comment: @DarkByte: Для первого добавьте триггер на MouseOver.

Comment: @DarkByte: Для второго напишите `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding}"/>`.

Comment: вот о том и речь что не видит имя кнопки.

Comment: @DarkByte: Давайте ваш код :) Или лучше новый вопрос, с этим вроде разобрались.

Comment: Обновил стартовый пост.

Comment: @DarkByte: Перенесите триггер в Template, как в этом ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518885/10105

Comment: да так работает, но не совсем. Оно работает только при наведении на текст. А если остается свободное пространство в хедере то при наведении на него ничего не происходит.

Comment: @DarkByte: Поставьте у внутреннего `Grid`'а `Background="Transparent"`

Comment: спасибо работает! А вот еще по поводу подсказки та же проблема. Подсказка появляется только при наведении на текст. А если есть свободное пространство, то при наведении на него нет подсказки.

Comment: @DarkByte: Тогда перенесите `ToolTip="{Binding}"` в `Grid`.

Comment: @VladD, Подскажите, а как сделать чтобы у каждой вкладки была уникальная картинка?

Comment: @maxwell: Ну например, вы можете положить картинку в VM. Или ID картинки в VM, и превращать его в картинку конвертером. А во View привязываться к картинке или ID.